# How to upload an image in windows phone application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How to upload image using HttpWebRequest or anything else plus I have to display results from the website in my application. Please help...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you please explain what you mean by showing the results - do you mean HTTP responses? Your image? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of how to do this which include for both the client and server at 
http://chriskoenig.net/2011/08/19/upload-files-from-windows-phone/

Answer (score -1):

You can use `WebClient.FileUpload` to upload images

Comment: can you please give me any example showing how to upload an image?

Comment: WebClient.FileUpload API not available on WP7